# How do I relate two similar text fields between users and content with user as argument?

Tags: entities, views

Getting a bit mixed up and need help with this. My restrictions are that I cannot use entity reference fields (or any reference type field); this is because Salesforce Suite isn't able to translate single strings to the array object normal reference fields use upon import and object creation.

I have two entity types, User and Content, which are dynamically created via the Salesforce Pull module. Both entities share a plain text field (*SFID*), which is the user's main ID.

The Content nodes' *SFID* field value can match any user's *SFID* field value, and I want to create a view that lists nodes on the user's page related in this way.

For example, I have the following users and nodes.

- User 5
  SFID 120
- Node A
  SFID 120
- Node B
  SFID 130
- Node C
  SFID 120

On /user/5/mynodes, I need a list of the nodes whose SFID matches the user's SFID. In this case above, the page would list the following nodes:

- Node A
- Node C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a View that lists nodes, containing a contextual filter that filters by SFID.  Do that, and what remains is the problem of how to pass the user's SFID value to the contextual filter.  There are many ways to do this, depending on how you're generating the user/%user/mynodes page.

### Panels / Page Manager approach

My go-to recommendation for this sort of thing is to use Panels / Page Manager to generate the user/%user/mynodes page, and embed your view there.  If you enable the Views Content module (bundled with CTools) you will have a new type of Views display available called "Content pane".  Build your view using this type of display.  In the view configuration when configuring this display there's an option for "Argument input".  You'll probably want to choose "input on pane config".  Then, when embedding the view in your page (using Page Manager) you'll be given the opportunity to plug in a token there from the ctools user context that represents the user's SFID.

### Custom module alternative:

Since you said you can't use Panels, your best alternative is probably to create your own menu callback at user/%user/mynodes wherein you extract the SFID from the user object and return the view by calling `views_embed_view()`.

This is greatly simplified, but here's the gist of it:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
 $items['user/%user/mynodes'] = array(
  'page callback' => 'mymodule_user_nodes',
  'page arguments' => array(1),
 );
 return $items;
}

function mymodule_user_nodes($account) {
 return views_embed_view('viewname', 'displayname', array($account->field_sfid['und'][0]['value']));
}
```

Note: I haven't tested that code, it's just off the top of my head.  I may have forgotten something.  Don't forget to add things like an `access callback` since I presume you'll want to limit access to this page.

### Views Field View or Entity Views Attach (EVA) alternative

This is a little bit icky but should work.  Either of the modules I listed ([Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) or [Entity Views Attach](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva)) will work for this approach.  I'll specifically outline how to do this with Views Field View but you could adapt these methods to EVA if you want; it would be similar.

You will make 2 views:

1. A view that lists users and accepts the user ID as a contextual filter.  So this view will always return only 1 single user (whatever user is passed in the URL).
2. The view that you've already likely created; the one that has a contextual filter that accepts a SFID value and lists nodes.

What we'll do is use view #1 to generate the page at user/%/mynodes, and view #2 will be embedded inside of view #1; view #2 will generate the actual list of nodes for us.

We'll assume you've created view #2 correctly already (it's basically what we've already discussed previously) and I'll focus on view #1.

1. Create a view based on the users table
2. Path for the view should be user/%/mynodes
3. Add a contextual filter to the view that filters on uid
4. Configure the view to output fields
5. Add the SFID field to the view, but check the "exclude from display" option so it's not actually displayed.  We add this to the view so that it's available as a substitution for our next step.
6. If you've installed Views Field View then you'll have a new field available called `Global: View`.  Add this to your view.  This field has a few settings; you'll need to select the name and display of view #2, above, and enter [!field_sfid] (this is the substitution token we get from the field we added in step 5) into the Contextual filters option.

Now you need only visit user/%/mynodes with an appropriate uid in place of the % and it should work.

Comment: Aw shoot - Panels is out for now as it's not approved for us to use on this project. Just plain old views. Did you have any specific suggestions for just Views? I tried a Content view with the SFID contextual filter, and then tried PHP Code to load the user from the argument, and doing $user->field_sfid['und'][0]['value'], but I'm getting an empty view result.

Comment: Woah, that's a little beyond my expertise. So I guess there's no UI-only way of doing this in Views? My fallback is to use Rules to post-process the values by fetching entities by field values, and creating a real entity reference field value.

Comment: I don't know the ins-and-outs of Rules all that well, so maybe it's possible to do with Rules.

Comment: @atwixtor I updated my answer with another option for you.

Comment: Also: don't be scared of doing the module approach.  I basically wrote the whole module for you, you just need to add a .info file and you're done.

Comment: Is the EVA / VFV approach "icky" because it's so 'heavy' compared to a custom module?

Comment: I guess I'd just call it icky because it's contorting Views for a purpose it's not *really* intended to be used for.  It'll work fine...and it's not probably even that terrible from a performance standpoint.  It might be a little unintuitive for anyone else who has to maintain the site.  Icky is probably too strong a word :).

Comment: Gotcha. Going to test this latest suggestion tomorrow and will get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: EVA was dead simple to use - it really is 'magic' as the module author suggests. I may revert to rules setting that 'real' entity reference field just to have that native connection, but until then your solution works perfectly. Thanks for all three sub-solutions! Hope this helps many other people.